# Multithreading inside NServiceBus handler

Tags: c#, .net, queue, nservicebus

Is there a scenario in which running async operations inside a handler is justified?
For example:

```
public class H1 : IMessageHandler<MyMessage>
{
    public async void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {
        await SendTxt(message);
        await SendEmail(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question identical to "Does NServiceBus support asynchronous handlers?"?

Comment: More or less. As I understand, NServiceBus manages its own threads. What I want to find out is whether I should avoid spinning more threads within Handlers (if yes then why) or if it's perfectly legal.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I want to make sure you understand one thing: neither async nor await nor async IO do start or block threads. Maybe this is a misunderstanding of yours.

Comment: @usr No additional threads are explicitly created, but it's possible that this change could result in paralleism that didn't exist before.  For example, if the event handler won't fire until all previous handlers completed, then having synchronous handlers would implicitly synchronize the code, and making them async would implicitly parallelize them.  Some of the continuations could also run in a thread pool thread (again, if there's no sync context) which may not be supported in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus does not support async handlers.

What are you trying to do?